# How to search image is present inside folder or not usinh PHP

Tags: php, image

I need one help.I need to search the image is present inside the folder or not by image name using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
$imagepath=http://localhost/koolfeedbackdev/admin/uploads/

$name=1ttb4wes4_MedRes_Product-presentation-2.jpg
```

i did like below but its not working.

```
$vimage="1ttb4wes4_MedRes_Product-presentation-2.jpg";
    if (file_exists("http://localhost/koolfeedbackdev/admin/uploads/".$vimage)){
       // $data['logo'] = empty($v["image2"]) ? "0" : $path . $v["image2"];
        echo 'yes';
    }else{
        echo 'no';
    }
```

Here i need the above image is present that particular path or not. Please help me.

Comment: You want to check if image exist in the given path or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: How to check if image file exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991425/php-how-to-check-if-image-file-exists)

Comment: I guess this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974003/how-to-search-images-by-name-inside-a-folder

Comment: Please check of existing questions and answers before posting new questions on SO.

Comment: @BhavikShah maybe he tried doing so that's i asked him if that is helpful or not if not then somebody will come at his rescue.

Comment: @SameerKhan1406: I was saying to Subhra. Not to you. Please forgive me.

Comment: @RuchishParikh : i tried using this path `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991425/php-how-to-check-if-image-file-exists` but its not working.

Comment: @RuchishParikh : Please check my post again.

Comment: Use system path, not url (e.g. file_exists( '/path/to/images/thumbnail.jpg' )).

Answer (score 0):

**file_exists() needs to use a file path on the hard drive, not a URL. So you should have something more like:**

```
<?php
$vimage="callbg.png";
    if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/images/".$vimage)){

        echo 'yes';
    }else{
        echo dirname(__FILE__);
    }
?>
```

Comment: or for PHP>=5.3.0 use 
"__DIR__"